# Lodash - Check for empty array in an array of objects using _.some

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this - say testArray. 
[image]
I need to check that for each object in array, if any of the saveNumbers array is empty, my function should return false.

My function is as follows:

```
  public checkSaveNumbers(): boolean {
    let result;
    if (this.testArray) {
      result = _.some(this.testArray, member => !member.saveNumbers.length);
    }
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Here, result is showing true for my above object where we can see that the first element in the array has saveNumbers array empty. I'd expect result to be false in that case. I want to achieve this using Lodash and I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Update:

As suggested in comments, I changed the code to following:

```
public checkSaveNumbers(): boolean {
  let result = true;
  if (this.testArray) {
    result = _.every(this.testArray, member => member.saveNumbers.length > 0); //as soon as the condition is false, result should become false otherwise result will remain true.
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

However, with this code, even when my saveNumbers array is non-empty for every member in testArray, I get result as false.

Comment: uhm.... .some returns true if one of them are true. In your case, one of them are true, so result will be true... simply negate it, or use `.every` and stop negating the length

Comment: if I negate it, it always returns false even if saveNumbers isn't empty.

Comment: `.some` returns true if any items in the array match the condition. Your condition is "is the array empty". so `result` will be true, if any of the items have an empty array. You want the opposite of that, so, negate `result`, or use `.every`

Comment: I don't see why anyone would downvote a question like this! 
@KevinB I changed my code to result = _.every(this.selectedMembers, member => member.saveNumbers.length); now, result shows false even when saveNumbers contains elements.

Comment: it's unclear. Your code does exactly what it should do, but you expect a different result... so you shoudl change it to have the expected result instead. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: You're negating the wrong thing. Think about what that change does. do you even know what `.some` does?

Comment: I'm not negating anything when I'm using every. Its simple. Check that every member has saveNumbers length > 0. As soon as this condition is not met, predicate will return false and iteration will stop. At that point, result should be assigned to false. But, If the saveNumbers.length > 0 for every member, then result will always be true. However, I'm getting result as false even when saveNumbers isn't empty for any member.

Comment: well, no, .some returns true, if any one of the items match the condition. it doesn't return what you return from the callback.... *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your function as follow:

```
function checkSaveNumber(testArray) {
    return !_.some(_.map(testArray, 'saveNumbers'), ['length', 0]);  
}
```

http://jsbin.com/domitexazo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4):

> If any of the saveNumbers array is empty, my function should return false.

You tried:

```
_.some(array, member => !member.saveNumbers.length)
```

But this means "**true** if at least one member has empty saveNumbers." Which is exactly the opposite of what you want.

So negate **the entire expression**.

```
!_.some(array, member => !member.saveNumbers.length)
```

UPDATE:

If this is also not working for you:

```
_.every(array, member => member.saveNumbers.length > 0)
```

then you have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: You're right. Although in logs I see that my array contains the values, it still gives me false with _.every. I think its something to do with my Angular app. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

another variant

```
!_.chain(testArray)
    .map('saveNumbers')
    .map(_.isEmpty)
    .some()
    .value()
```